# Is there a tool to print X (XCB) server initialization state?

Tags: logging, x11, xcb

**Context:** Using tools like `xtruss` one can log calls made to a pre-existing X server from an X client.

**Problem:** I'm trying to debug a program that *sets up an XWayland server* on a `DISPLAY` (through XCB) that clients can then connect to. I'm worried that the initialization of this server is messed up.

**Question:** Is there a tool that can allow me to see the logs of the initialization of the X server?

Comment: `less /var/log/Xorg.0.log`  in a terminal?